# Can't connect to Browsermob-proxy ProxyServerError

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browsermob-proxy, browsermob

I'm new to using browsermob-proxy utility tool. Here's my code that runs perfectly fine on my local instance but when I try it on my ec2 instance(using headless browser) gives me an error:

```
 raise ProxyServerError("Can't connect to Browsermob-Proxy")
browsermobproxy.exceptions.ProxyServerError: Can't connect to Browsermob-Proxy
```

The only difference between my local and ec2 instance setup is that on ec2 it's running on the headless browser.

Code Snippet:

```
def start_proxy_server():
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        # check whether the process name matches
        if proc.name() == "browsermob-proxy":
            proc.kill()
    dict = {'port': 7190}
    server = Server(path="path_to_browswermob/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy", options=dict)
    server.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    proxy = server.create_proxy()
    time.sleep(1)
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(proxy.proxy)) #Configure chrome options
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('path_to_chromedriver/chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver.get("www.google.com")
    return driver, proxy
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Using headless should not be an issue in my opinion. (facing the same problem)

Comment: Do you have java installed on your ec2?

Comment: Yes, I do have java installed on my ec2 @George312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with some changes

```
def start_proxy_server():
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    # check whether the process name matches
    if proc.name() == "browsermob-proxy":
        proc.kill()

dict = {'port': 8080}
server = Server(path="path_to_browswermob/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy", options=dict)
server.start()
time.sleep(1)
proxy = server.create_proxy()
time.sleep(1)
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(proxy.proxy)) #Configure chrome options
```